# Setting timeouts for adding classes in a for loop Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, settimeout

I'm having trouble with adding a setTimeout like feature in my for loop - I'm using it to iterate through each child element of a parent div, then add a class to each of those in the meantime, which adds a fadeIn, and I wanted to add a delay after adding each class

```js
var children = $("#phototitle span");

for (var i = 0; i <= children.length; i++) {
  var x = children[i]
  $("#phototitle span:nth-of-type(" + i + ")").addClass("flip-in-hor-bottom");
  console.log(x);
}
```

setTimeout doesn't seem to work in this, it either only adds the class to the first or last child element.

Thanks

Comment: Your code doesn't show any use of `setTimeout()`. Also, please add the relevant HTML and CSS so that we can reproduce your issue and provide a working solution.

Comment: where is your attempt with setTimeout?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that will add the class and set a timeout before moving to the next, something along these lines:

```js
let children = document.querySelectorAll('.child')

function addClass(className, idx) {

  if (typeof idx === 'undefined') {
    idx = 0
  }
  
  if (children.length>idx) {
    children[idx].classList.add(className)
    setTimeout(function() {
     addClass(className, idx+1)
    }, 1000)
  }
}

addClass('changed')
```

```css
#container {
 padding: 4px;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}

.child {
  background: #02042e;
  color: white;
}

.changed {
  background: #1010ff;
 }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="child">Child One</div>
  <div class="child">Child Two</div>
  <div class="child">Child Three</div>
  <div class="child">Child Four</div>
  <div class="child">Child Five</div>
  <div class="child">Child Six</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
// Get all elements
var children = $('#phototitle span');

// For each element
children.each(function(i, e) {

    // Get the element, and sets the delay for the element
    var element = $(e),
        delay   = i * 1000; // One second delay = 1000 ms

    // Set the timeout for the element
    setTimeout(delay, function() {
        element.addClass('flip-in-hor-bottom');
    });

});
```

I think that will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following. It is self invoking function which will call it self after every 1 second until `i` become `children.length`(until it traverse all required node)

```js
var children = $("#phototitle span");

(function myLoop (i) {  
   setTimeout(function () {   
      $("#phototitle span:nth-of-type(" + i + ")").addClass("white");
      if (i++ < children.length){ 
        myLoop(i); 
      }
   }, 1000)
})(1);
```

```css
.white{
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="phototitle">
  <span>1</span><br />
  <span>2</span><br />
  <span>3</span><br />
  <span>4</span><br />
  <span>5</span>
</div>
```